# How to get Full State names instead of State Code?

Tags: here-api

Its a wonderful api. However, I am looking for full state names like "California" instead "CA" or "Texas" instead of "TX". How do I get this?

Comment: which API are you referring to specifically?

Answer (score 0):

If the platform cannot do it for you, I suggest to create an associative array, if you plan to use it frequently.
In PHP would be something as:

```
$states = array(
    "CA" => "California",
    "TX" => "Texas"
);
```

Thus, if you have

```
$aState = "TX";
```

You can get "Texas" by calling:

```
$longNameState = $states[$aState];
```

Array should have all the states.